# Self Hosting Raspberry Pi for Discord Bot

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+

I've sucessfully set up my Raspberry Pi to host my Discord Bot, from [these instructions (albeit a bit outdated)](https://anidiots.guide/hosting/hosting-on-a-raspberry-pi), but from what I know, I had to connect a monitor and keyboard to start the raspberry pi up and connect to it. I know you can use the Raspberry Pi for hosting different servers, and it doesn't require a monitor or keyboard, it's just the pi board itself. So I was wondering if it were possible if I could set up a server on the Raspberry Pi that doesn't require the monitor or mouse at all that just automatically keeps my bot on, provided that it's always plugged in.

---

TL;DR Is there a method where I could host a Discord bot without having to connect the Raspberry Pi to a monitor, keyboard, and mouse to manipulate it?

For reference, I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 (B+, I think)

Comment: `man systemd.service`

Comment: Could you elaborate on that comment more?

Comment: that gives you a manual page for systemd services - which is how you would achieve your task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a method where I could host a Discord bot without having to connect the Raspberry Pi to a monitor, keyboard, and mouse to manipulate it?

Just enable `ssh` and use a ssh-client on your management computer to connect to the RasPi on your network. How to enable `ssh` look at [SSH (Secure Shell)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md). Then you can login to the RasPi and have a text console available to manage all things. This is mostly used to remotely manage server.

Comment: I've already got SSH enabled. Would I have to keep the text console always on in my computer? Is there a way to eliminate the need keep it on at all times as well or is that not possible?

Comment: Never mind, I did some experimenting and realized that it wasn't necessary. Thanks for your help though!